Underlying correspondence of calculating the imaginary part of the effective Lagrangian in sQED
I was wondering if there is a correspondence/underlying equivalence between the heat kernel, tunnelling, and Bogolubov approaches for calculating the imaginary part of the effective Lagrangian in sQED for a constant electric field. The sQED Lagrangian reads,
\begin{equation}
    \mathscr{L}_{sQED} = -\frac{1}{4}\left(F^{\mu\nu}\right)^{2} + \left|D_{\mu}\phi\right|^{2}-\mu^{2}\left|\phi\right|^{2} 
\end{equation}
where $D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}+ i A_{\mu}$ and $\mu$ is the mass of the scalar quanta. The heat kernel/Schwinger approach calculates the imaginary part of the effective lagrangian by firstly computing the eigenvalues (which are $\lambda = 2 i E (n + \frac{1}{2})+\mu^{2}+k_{y}^2+k_{z}^2$) and tracing over them. This gives,
\begin{equation}
    \mathscr{L}_{eff}[A]= \frac{1}{2}E^{2}- \frac{1}{16\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ds}{s^{3}}e^{-\mu^{2}s}\left[Es\;\text{csc}\left(Es\right)-1-\frac{E^{2}s^{2}}{6}\right].
\end{equation}
The imaginary contribution follows from the poles and is,
\begin{equation}
     2\Im{\left(\mathscr{L}_{eff}[A]\right)} = \frac{E^{2}}{8 \pi^{3}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{2}}e^{-\frac{\mu^{2}\pi n}{E}} .
 \label{a}
\end{equation}
The Bogolubov coefficients are related to the imaginary part by,
\begin{equation}
    2\Im{\left(W\right)} = 2\int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g}\text{tr}\big\{\text{ln}\left|\alpha\right|\big\} = \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g}\text{tr}\big\{\text{ln}\left(1+N\right)\big\},
\end{equation}
where $N$ is the mean number of particles created and $\alpha$ is a Bogolubov coefficient. The Bogolubov coefficient(s) can be found by calculating mode solutions in the far past and future and expanding the future modes in terms of the past modes. Lastly, the tunnelling approach provides a relation between the transmission and the imaginary part of the effective lagrangian by,
\begin{equation}
    \prod_{\lambda}T_{r,\lambda} =\text{exp}\left[-2 V \Im{\left(\mathcal{L}_{eff}\right)}\right].
\end{equation}
All three approaches provide the exact same answer to the imaginary part of the effective action.
